# Adding mapquest to a site in microsoft expression web 4

Tags: html, email, mapquest

I am interning at an insurance and company and fire hall. Their fire hall is lacking the ability to have a direct to mapquest feature, curious if anyone would be able to help me or point me in the direction because I have done this with other software but not with Expression in html.

Comment: I was not given too much detaib but can elaborate on this if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to embed a map on the page or do you want to have users click a link to send them off to MapQuest.com?

For example, this URL will open on MapQuest.com and show the destination and the user can enter their address to get directions to this destination:
http://mapq.st/directions?q1=1555 Blake Street Denver CO 80202&maptype=map

Comment: I was kinda trying to go for a lightbox that would pop up with mapquest inside or click on a location link that would redirect them to mapquest with the building location already prompted on in the destination field

Answer (score 0):

the second option, I want to just make it simple for users and basically all they have to do is add their address and hit directions. Otherwise they may be mad that they have to cpy and paste the address from the site instead.